# Set TextView.Text values for preview screen only

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to set some TextView.Text values in an XML layout that will show up in the rendered preview screen to help with modelling, but are not carried over to the app when it is run.

I used to do this previously but I cannot remember the name of the attribute that needs to be set. I've been digging around in the documentation but I can't find how I used to do this, how is it achieved?

Comment: Perfect, thanks @rlay3

Answer (score 0):

simply use *tools:text="YOUR TEXT"* in the layout

anything that you set with *tools* instead of *android* will only show up in the preview

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to Designtime Layout Attributes. See here: http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes